# fgets c++ подставить значение

Tags: c++, input, консоль, firebird

исходники firebird. строка ввода fgets. нужно что бы при вызове функции в консоль уже была введена строка которую пользователь может редактировать. Сам я пока не догнал. Подскажите метод, ну или другой способ считывания который позволит выполнить данный функционал. Приветствуется возможность реагирования консоли по нажатию клавиши tab, например, пользователь подвел курсор к нужному месту нажал TAB тут же заканчивается ввод, а мы получаем строку из консоли и позицию курсора. Спасибо

Comment: какая ОС? Кроссплатформенно врядли получится.

Comment: в моём случае win 64x, стандартная библиотека stdio

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx этим установить позицию курсора. Tab отловить не сложно. Получить тоже самое.

Comment: Можно использовать `\n` без `\r` - тогда курсор "бежит" вначало, потом пишем столько, что б курсор остался в месте где был (кроссплатформенно).

Comment: Если под виндой - можно заморочится ф-цией WriteConsoleOutputxxxx - там семейство функций вывода.

Comment: ReadConsoleInput или PeekConsoleInput (если без задержки на ожидание ввода).

Comment: если интересует платформенное решение, то `libreadline` (GNU GPL) или `libedit` (BSD). Клиент firebird, в частности уже использует вторую.

Comment: @nick_n_a Добрый день, протупил, не обратил внимание на ваш комментарий, а это оказалось ответом, пришел к этому через 20 дней. Напишите ответом, отмечу как правильный ответ! Может кому еще пригодится

Answer (score 0):

То что требуется - вывести в экранный буфер ввода консоли строку (для редактирования), решил задачу с помощью WriteConsoleInput! Всем спасибо!